# grep contents of files based on a list of files

Tags: awk, grep, find, qemu

Running CentOS 6.5, qemu-kvm.

I have a script which builds a list of running VM's. I want to pull information from those .xml files of only the VM's that are running.

`cat /dev/null > /<path>/runlist
virsh list --all|grep running|awk -F" " '{print $2}' > /<path>/runlist.tmp`

Now that I have the list of running vm's, I want to match them to their appropriate .xml files in a directory listing that includes the .xml files of all of our vm's and pull bits of information out.

I know that I can:

```
grep <info> </path/file.xml>
```

But how do I get that middle bit that will parse the runlist file against the directory listing and only search for the information from the files that are pertinent to the running VM's.

---

Sample xml file:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>"X"</name>
  <uuid>"X"</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>"X"</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>"X"</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='X'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/<path>/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/path/file.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='X'/>
      <source bridge='br1'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Comment: You'll need to show us that xml file.

Comment: An update:
I am using sed to append the .xml file extension to the end of each vm name in the runlist file.

Comment: @MatthewLeeAllen-Goebel: So you if runlist have `a.xml` and `b.xml`, you only want to search <info> from those files?

Comment: awk can do what grep does: `virsh | awk '/running/ {print $2}`

Comment: @Gnouc - yes. I want to search a.xml and b.xml, but not c.xml or d.xml.

Comment: @glennjackman - Thanks for the more elegant way of getting the same information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is

```
grep -f /path/to/runlist /path/to/file.xml
```

But I think this is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): without thinking about **how** to solve the question, what are you trying to do?

---

Given that `runlist` is a file containing xml filenames, I'd use an xml processing tool (like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)) to extract the vcpu:

```
$ cat runlist
sample1.xml
sample2.xml
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v /domain/name -o $'\t' -v /domain/currentMemory -o $'\t' -v /domain/vcpu -nl $(< ./runlist)
"X"     "X"     1
"XX"    256     16
```

Comment: I want to grab 'vcpu', disk, and memory information to calculate and total up. The purpose is to notify system admins and users building VM's that they have enough resources left on a Host server to build a virtual guest, and to kill a build if there are not enough resources.

Comment: Thus, you need to know what is running, what resources it uses, and how much left you have.

Comment: `grep` is not the best tool for parsing xml. Why don't you provide a sample xml file?

Comment: There are only two pieces of information I need out of this (see edited answer) XML file. The "vcpu" line and the "current memory" line. But I need those bits of information for each running virtual guest on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only want to get information from list of files in runlist. You can:

```
grep <info> -- $(cat runlist)
```

Comment: Thanks!

command is now thus:

'grep vcpu $(cat runlist)|awk -F":" '{print $2}'|sed s,\>,\ ,g|sed s,\<,\ ,g|awk -F" " '{print $3}' > /<path>/core'

Comment: This works from the command line, but unfortunately doesn't work within a bash script. Keeps throwing an unknow file/directory error.

Comment: @MatthewLeeAllen-Goebel: You must use `/path/to/runlist` if use in script.

Comment: I tried a fully qualified path. It still threw the error.

Comment: Weird. Try the raw data link: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6JLvgkiy

Comment: @MatthewLeeAllen-Goebel: Are you sure the error due to the line contains `grep <info> -- $(cat runlist)` command? You can use `bash -x yourscript` to see debug information.

Comment: I will run the script again and check the error message.

Comment: Error message IS pointing to another part of the script that is not fully qualified pathway. My bad.